# Serving several .html files in one handler as separate files. net/http and html/template

Tags: javascript, go

How does one serve several .html files in one handler as separate files to ajax to distribute to specific html fields?

How the format should look (html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        //AJAX Code
    </script>
    <body>
        <form action="/submit">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="field1"></div>
        <div id="field2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How the format should look (Golang):

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/context"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
}

func submitHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //Serves 2 .html files
}

var tpl *template.Template

func main() {

    tpl, _ = template.ParseGlob("*.html")
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/submit", submitHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux))

}
```

Comment: Normally you would include multiple values in the response, or make multiple requests from JavaScript and include some parameter to let the server know which response you want.

Comment: In what way would you pass multiple values in such a way that you could differentiate them in the Javascript? Eventually what would be the best way to do so.

Comment: You say you want to return two `.html` files, but to me it looks like you want to return some content that goes inside the `div`s, is that correct? In that case, you might return `<fields><field1><p>Some content for field1</p></field1><field2><p>Some more content</p></field2></fields>`. Then use JavaScript to extract the subset you need and put them in field1 and field2.